# AsyncProcessor equivalent in Spring Integration

Tags: asynchronous, apache-camel, spring-integration

In Camel, there is an [AsyncProcessor](http://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-processing.html) . Is there any equivalent in Spring Integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several components in Spring Integration which deal with the async hands-off.

The `@MessagingGateway` can be configured with the `ListenableFuture` what is fully similar to mentioned `AsyncProcessor` in the Apache Camel: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#async-gateway.

Also this Gateway can have `Mono` return type for Reactive Streams manner of async processing.

For simple thread shifting and parallel processing there is an `ExecutorChannel`. The `PublishSubscribeChannel` also can be configured with the `TaskExecutor` for parallelism: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration.

The `QueueChannel` can also be used for some kind of async tasks.

At the same time any POJO invocation component (e.g. `@ServiceActivator`) can simply deal with the `ListenableFuture` as a return from the underlying POJO and perform similar async callback work: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#async-service-activator

Comment: Hi @artem thanks for the response. Could you point me to the Mono return type sample example if any.

Comment: The Reference Manual clearly demonstrates that part: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.M5/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#_reactor_mono

Comment: Thanks @artem for the link.